# Getting iTune to add remote items to library

Tags: itunes, audio, streaming

I keep my music on a local Ubuntu server. Is there any way I can get iTunes to recognize the networked directory as part of its library?

Answer (score 2):

you can try  mt-daapd (firefly server) to serve media files to your 
iTunes from your ubuntu machine. 
Setup it on your server* and then add in Itunes Preferences->Advanced where your library is..

*this is a tutorial on how to install mt-daapd on your ubuntu server

http://all-tech-thoughts.blogspot.gr/2010/09/how-to-setup-firefly-mt-daapd-on-ubuntu.html

Also bear in mind sometimes for some versions of itunes mt-daapd compatibility breaks.
Updating to current itunes version usually helps...

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you add some details about where to get the recommended application from and how to configure both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose it in iTunes' Advanced preferences as the iTunes Media folder location. It also needs to be mounted before you launch iTunes, otherwise iTunes won't be able to find your media.